# How to get numeric values from alpha numeric using SQL query and sort by the numeric

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL DB

```
Colum1

Drill 14"
Drill 15"
Drill 10" 
Drill 11"
Drill 5"
```

I want to get the numerical values and sort it like so

```
Colum1

5
10
11
14
15
```

Note that i don't want to use declare because it does not accepted by the Jasper - so if there is simple SQL that can do it should be fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use <kbd>[**`SUBSTRING_INDEX`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index)</kbd>

`ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(Colum1,' ', -1)+0 ASC`

---

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @str := 'Drill 11';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',-1)+0 AS number;
```

**Output:**

```
number 
11
```

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I saw the fiddle it still include the words Drill -- i want to remove them and get only the numbers

Comment: Check this [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920b41/2/0). Thanks a million @Tim

Comment: Alternatively you can use `CAST` function to achieve this. Check this [**fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920b41/3/0) too. @rookie_coder

Comment: By the way is the sql treat 12 1/4 inch as numbers or string? i meant the 1/4

Comment: You cannot make it work for this kind of numeric strings. @rookie_coder

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM Table_Name 
        WHERE Colum1 REGEXP '^[0-9]+$';
```

Comment: Brilliant this is also working...thanks but only specifically for the one that has numbers inside maybe because it is put in where?